# How to Initialize a Min Heap?

Tags: python, arrays, queue, priority-queue, heap

I'm trying to figure out how I can initialize a min heap using an array. So far my function looks like this:

```
    def start_heap(self,n):
        # None positions to be filled with Nodes
        arr = [none][] * n
        for i in arr:
            heapify(i) 

    def heapify(self):
        start = self.parent(len(self) - 1) # Start at parent of last leaf
        for j in range(start, -1, -1):      # going to and including the root.
            self.heapify_down(j)

 def heapify_down(self, i):
        n = len(self._pq)
        left, right = self.left(i), self.right(i)
        if left < n:
            child = left
            if right < n and self.pq[right] < self.pq[left]:
                child = right
            if self.pq[child] < self.pq[i]:
                self.swap(i, child)
                self.heapify_down(child)
```

Heapify Down Pseudocode:

```
Heapify-down(H,i): Let n = length(H) If 2i>n then
Terminate with H unchanged Else if 2i<n then
Let left=2i, and right=2i+1
Let j be the index that minimizes key[H[left]] and key[H[right]] Else if 2i=n then
Let j=2i Endif
If key[H[j]] < key[H[i]] then
swap the array entries H[i] and H[j] Heapify-down(H , j)
Endif
```

I'm going to build a simple node class that just holds data but I'm not sure how to actually get the start_heap function working. Keep in mind n is the maximum number of elements that can be stored.

Comment: Why do you have an `n` in the first place? You're trying to create an n-element heap when you don't have any elements.

Comment: To specify the max

Comment: What is `start_heap` supposed to do? Initialize an empty heap? It would help if you could provide a desired output / example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Since `arr` is a local variable, it is useless. You would need an attribute. What is `none`? Did you mean `None`? Why would you create `arr`? Isn't an empty list just fine? You can always check its length as it grows. Why would you call `heapify` repeatedly? You should only call it once, as it already has the necessary loop itself. As to your question: you initialise a heap by setting it to the empty list. No need to call `heapify` on an empty list. That's all.

Comment: Can you provide your `heapify_down` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks on the code you provided (not on the code you didn't provide):

- `arr` is a local variable, so whatever you do with it, once the function returns, that `arr` will be out of scope... and lost. You need an attribute or else subclass `list`
- It is not common practice to "allocate" the array and fill it with `None`. In Python lists are dynamic, so you don't need to reserve slots ahead of time. You just need an empty list to start with.
- There is no need to call `heapify` when the heap is empty.
- There is certainly no need to call `heapify` many times in a loop. All the logic for heapifying is already present in that method, so no need to call it on each index individually. But as stated in the previous point: no need to call it on an empty list -- there is nothing to move.

So the correction is quite basic:

```
    def start_heap(self, max_size):
        self.max_size = max_size
        self._pq = []
```

Then, in many of your other methods, you will have to work with `self._pq` and `self.max_size`.

For instance, it could have a method that indicates whether the heap is full:

```
    def is_full(self):
        return len(self._pq) >= self.max_size
```

If you have an `add` method, it would first check if there is still room:

```
   def add(self, node):
       if is_full(self):
           raise ValueError("Cannot add value to the heap: it is full")
       # ... rest of your code ...
```

Comment: I've added my heapify_down code

Comment: Why does your `heapify_down` code access both `._pq` and `pq`? It looks like you overcomplicated your heap implementation with many unnecessary methods and properties.

Comment: I was trying to store the node values in a wrapper Node class and place those into dictionaries to avoid collisions in my dictionary

Comment: I've also added my pseudocode for my heapify_down if that helps

Comment: I have updated my answer to use `._pq` which was the part I was interested in. I think my post answers your question with that missing piece resolved.

Comment: do you have any suggestions for me to improve my heapify_up and heapify_down functions?

Comment: Sure, but this is not the place. If you want your code to be reviewed, consider [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There are guidelines on how to post there, so be sure to follow them. One condition is that your code works. If it doesn't, then ask a new question here, focusing on one problem.

Comment: please check my question here if you have knowledge about prim's algorithm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71819785/python-key-error-implementing-prims-algorithm